# Xamarin.Forms CarouselView: lower opacity of unselected items

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, carousel

I have a Xamarin.Forms Vertical CarouselView where the PeakAreaInsets is set pretty high so I can see multiple items in the list at once. I want a way to be able to visually show which item in the list is currently "focused" or selected. Is there a way to dynamically change the opacity of Items in a Carousel View as you scroll through it, so as to show which one is currently selected?

Here's a snippet of my code if that helps:

```
<CarouselView ItemsSource="{Binding Days}"
                  CurrentItem="{Binding SelectedDay}"
                  VerticalOptions="Center"
                  HorizontalOptions="Center"
                  PeekAreaInsets="300"
                  x:Name="DayCarousel">
        <CarouselView.ItemsLayout>
            <LinearItemsLayout SnapPointsAlignment="Center"
                               SnapPointsType="Mandatory"
                               Orientation="Vertical"/>
        </CarouselView.ItemsLayout>
        <CarouselView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <StackLayout Spacing="0"
                             Orientation="Vertical"
                             HorizontalOptions="Center"
                             VerticalOptions="Center"
                             Margin="30,10">
                    <Label Text="{Binding FormattedDate}"
                           HorizontalOptions="Center"
                           VerticalOptions="Center"
                           Style="{StaticResource LabelStyle}"/>
                    <Label Text="{Binding TitleText}"
                           HorizontalOptions="Center"
                           VerticalOptions="Center"
                           Style="{StaticResource LabelHeader1Style}"/>
                    <StackLayout.GestureRecognizers>
                        <TapGestureRecognizer Command="{Binding BindingContext.SelectDay, Source={x:Reference this}}"
                                              CommandParameter="{Binding .}"/>
                    </StackLayout.GestureRecognizers>
                </StackLayout>
            </DataTemplate>
        </CarouselView.ItemTemplate>
    </CarouselView>
```

Here is an illustration of what I am looking for:

[image]

Comment: How about adding an Opacity attribute to the StackLayout and bind it to a property of your viewcell's viewmodel. You can set the new items opacity whenever the selection changes. You could set the new items opcaity to 1 and all the other items opacity to 0.75 for example

Comment: @MouseOnMars You the man! yep, don't know why I didn't do that in the first place but that works great. thank you!! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to @MouseOnMars

Here is the xaml that made this work.

```
        <CarouselView ItemsSource="{Binding Days}"
                  CurrentItem="{Binding SelectedDay}"
                  VerticalOptions="Center"
                  HorizontalOptions="Center"
                  PeekAreaInsets="300"
                  x:Name="DayCarousel">
        <CarouselView.ItemsLayout>
            <LinearItemsLayout SnapPointsAlignment="Center"
                               SnapPointsType="Mandatory"
                               Orientation="Vertical"/>
        </CarouselView.ItemsLayout>
        <CarouselView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <StackLayout Spacing="0"
                             Orientation="Vertical"
                             HorizontalOptions="Center"
                             VerticalOptions="Center"
                             Margin="30,10"
                             Opacity=".25">
                    <StackLayout.Triggers>
                        <DataTrigger TargetType="StackLayout"
                                     Binding="{Binding IsSelected}"
                                     Value="True">
                            <Setter Property="Opacity"
                                    Value="1"/>
                        </DataTrigger>
                    </StackLayout.Triggers>
                    <Label Text="{Binding FormattedDate}"
                           HorizontalOptions="Center"
                           VerticalOptions="Center"
                           Style="{StaticResource LabelStyle}"/>
                    <Label Text="{Binding TitleText}"
                           HorizontalOptions="Center"
                           VerticalOptions="Center"
                           Style="{StaticResource LabelHeader1Style}"/>
                    <StackLayout.GestureRecognizers>
                        <TapGestureRecognizer Command="{Binding BindingContext.SelectDay, Source={x:Reference this}}"
                                              CommandParameter="{Binding .}"/>
                    </StackLayout.GestureRecognizers>
                </StackLayout>
            </DataTemplate>
        </CarouselView.ItemTemplate>
    </CarouselView>
```

I had to add a new bool property "IsSelected" to the Model that the ItemTemplate is bound to. Then I had to add some logic in my "SelectedDay" Property on my Page ViewModel to turn on and off the IsSelected bool. Additionally since I am binding the CarouselView directly to a model I had to raise property Changed on the model for IsSelected whenever it was switched on or off.

Answer (score 0):

@Jonathan Cook: I've come up with a more general solution that doesn't rely on ViewModel bindings. Works like a charm and you don't have to mess around with it in your ViewModel.

```
<CarouselView>
    <CarouselView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackLayout Opacity=".3">
                <View.Triggers>
                    <DataTrigger TargetType="StackLayout" Value="True">

                        <!-- Using MultiBinding as we are going to compare two bound objects -->
                        <DataTrigger.Binding>

                            <!-- Simple IMultiValueConverter that checks for equality of the two values in the array -->
                            <MultiBinding Converter="{x:Static s:CommonConverters.MultiEquals}">
                                <MultiBinding.Bindings>
                                    <Binding />
                                    <Binding Path="CurrentItem" 
                                             Source="{RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type CarouselView}}"/>
                                </MultiBinding.Bindings>
                            </MultiBinding>
                        </DataTrigger.Binding>

                        <Setter Property="Opacity" Value="1" />
                    </DataTrigger>
                </View.Triggers>

                <!-- Template content --> 
            </StackLayout>
        </DataTemplate>
    </CarouselView.ItemTemplate>
</CarouselView>
```